# The MAC layer in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using omnet++-5.4.1, veins-4.7.1 and sumo-0.25.0 to simulate vehicle frame transmission.

About the behavior of the EDCA in the mac layer in WAVE, in my understanding the waiting time to send can be obtained by the following calculation.

waiting time = AIFS[AC] + backoff
AIFS[AC] = SIFS + AIFSN[AC] * slotlength

However, in the startContent function of Mac 1609_4.cc, it is written as follows

```
if (idleTime > possibleNextEvent) {
    DBG_MAC << "Could have already send if we had it earlier" << std::endl;
    //we could have already sent. round up to next boundary
    simtime_t base = idleSince + DIFS;
    possibleNextEvent =  simTime() - simtime_t().setRaw((simTime() - base).raw() % SLOTLENGTH_11P.raw()) + SLOTLENGTH_11P;
}
```

Even during simulation, transmission is performed without waiting for the time calculated just after the transmission request has occurred.

As described above, it is considered that the operation of the original EDCA (CSMA / CA) has not been performed and the busyness of the channel is not sensed.

I do not understand enough about this Mac layer? Please let me know if I missed some information.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If the implementation in Veins is correct? If your understanding is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood.

I was calling the sendDown function in TraCIDemo 11p.cc.

In my opinion, after the sendDown function was called, it waited for AIFS and backoff time, then sent a frame.

However, in Veins, after the sendDown function was called, AIFS and backoff time were taken into account by inverse computing whether the channel was free from that point.